# Python Pandas: add value if same date, then drop row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
c1        c2       c3 
A     2017-03-17    1 
B     2017-03-17    2 
C     2017-05-27    8 
D     2017-09-02    4
```

I want to add the values in c3 if the dates in c2 are the same and then remove the duplicate date row keeping the first.
Output should look like the following:

```
c1        c2       c3 
A     2017-03-17    3 
C     2017-05-27    8 
D     2017-09-02    4
```

I am using df.drop_duplicates with keep=first to drop duplicates based on the date, but of course that also removes the value in c3 which I would like to keep.

Comment: do you need to keep c1? if no need, you can use groupby('c2').sum()

Comment: But which value should c1 have?

Comment: Yes I need to keep c1. It should be "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) on `c1` and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum) on `c3`

```py
df.groupby('c2').agg({'c1': 'first', 'c3': 'sum'}).reset_index()

           c2 c1  c3
0  2017-03-17  A   3
1  2017-05-27  C   8
2  2017-09-02  D   4
```